# Private network monitoring

Tags: etherscan

I have created a private ethereum blockchain. My question is:
How to monitor a private Ethereum blockchain? Is there an open source project to do so like etherscan

Comment: What type of monitoring you want to perform?

Comment: more details please

Comment: @ismael, majd-tl:  as in etherscan, I want to monitor block and transaction and the details about each one of them

Comment: The second answer has a link to an open source block explorer [BlockScout](https://github.com/blockscout/blockscout).

Comment: thank you @ismael for your answer. This is very helful.